# Is center of symmetry only valid for symmetric substituents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

The given compound is optically active. Initially I had reasoned that the compound has center of symmetry( two xylene groups across each other). Why doesn't it have a center of symmetry?

[image]

**Source:** MS Chouhan, Advanced Problems In Organic Chemistry, Page 116 (Chapter Isomerism Level 2 q6a)

Comment: It probably racemises pretty quickly.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't think so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You assume too much, starting with the words "The given compound". *There is no given compound*. The picture corresponds to quite a few ***different*** compounds, and here is why.

As I told you before on a remotely similar question, the biphenyl fragment totally can't be planar. The xylene substituents must be rotated so their *ortho* methyl group points either up or down relative to the plane of the central ring. Since there are two of them, we have three options: "both up", "both down", and "one up, one down". The first two compounds are indeed chiral, and enantiomers of each other. The third one is centrosymmetric, just as you've reasoned.

Comment: It was a question ; the book had provided that picture and asked to state whether it was chiral or achiral. How do I figure out which of the three isomeric states would it be in?  (the question book specifies whether the bonds are in or out of the plane{through wedges and dashes} ). So I was taking the compound to be planar (which is not possible as you did tell me earlier).

Comment: If you have wedges and dashes, then you have one specific isomer. If you don't, then you have all three at once. In that case any answer shorter than mine would be incomplete.

Comment: @IvanNeretin "one up, one down" would that stereoisomer's m-xylene rings be _exactly_ perpendicular to the central benzene ring? Because if they are not exactly perpendicular, and rather inclined at some angle, then the centrosymmetry would be lost.

Comment: The central symmetry would still be there if they are inclined at _the same_ angle in the opposite direction.

Answer (score -2):

[image]
Look at the picture, although the two methyl groups are located equidistant from the centre but they aren't in opposite direction. Therefore, no centre of symmetry and so it's optically active.